# Communicate with Flash object from WebBrowser with C# .Net

Tags: flash, object, controls, invoke

I am trying to make myself a simple metacafe uploader, and I am using the webbrowser to do that.
Everything was working great with loggin in, navigating to upload page etc...
I used the HtmlElement and setAttribute/Invoke to click and set the text fields:

HtmlElement password = wb.Document.All["sPass"];
assword.SetAttribute("value", this.password);

Now I have a problem. To upload a video to metacafe, you first need to click on a flash button caleld Upload. There, a window appears to select a file, and after you press OK, the upload begins and you can enter the form information.
My question is this:
How can I enter the video file without seeing a popup window? Knowing that it's flash . Here is how the flash object looks:

http://www.sodevrom.net/sample.html

Above I copied only the part from the upload page that it's important to me. As you can see, a simple flash file appears. Now I want to simulate the click/enter of file without showing the file window.

Any ideas on how I can do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this:

1. Get Firefox and [FlashTracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3469/) (or another add-on that allows inspection of packets sended by the Flash applet to the server).
2. Emulate and send those packets using C#.

I've already done that using C#, but not with Metacafe. Apparently they do not have any kind of open API to make things easier, so I guess you do not have any other option.

BTW, are you sure that you are allowed (legally) to do that?

Comment: Hello, why shouldn't I be allowed to upload video to my account.

Comment: I'm just saying that you should check their usage rules. I did just now - it seems you *could* use an automation tool, but you must keep your post rate to a "human-like" level... http://wikicafe.metacafe.com/en/Metacafe:Usage_Rules

Comment: In the end I used HTTPanalyzerto track all the requests made by the flash application.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used HTTPanalyzer to track all the requests made by the flash application.
 I analyzed all requests and created my own POST/GET class to make things happen.

So whenever you don't know what's going in the background, try the software I stated above and track all http requests.