# PostMessage call steals focus from siblings

Tags: c#

Good Evening.
I understand the question may seem kind of odd, so let me explain my problem a little bit : Ii'm building a Windows From Application, that is able to open multiple Child Form, each one containing a WebBrowser component that loads a Flash animaion.

Now, I need to simulate a click on a given opened form, without it showing up on top of every other. To simulate the click, I'm using a code quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11161632/533599 : I had to implement 2 changes

1. I have to stop to the "Internet Explorer_Server" , since I don't
   have a "MacromediaFlashPlayerActiveX" in the handles chain
2. For the
       click to fire, I have to "make it double", that is, mouse down, up,
       down, up.

The code works quite well, and the click is fired, but everytime it does, the target Form gets focus and pops up on top of all his siblings ( but stays behind every other window I've opened over them). Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Well, that's all pretty normal.  Just like what happens when you use the mouse to click, that click brings the window to the foreground.  Fixing this when Flash is around is going to be mighty difficult, it is an entirely different process that gets the click.  Best not to do this.

Comment: Any suggestion on how should I do it if I HAVE to?

Comment: I guess intercepting the WM_MOUSEACTIVATE message by overriding WndProc() might work.  No idea, really.

Comment: I've managed to find a workaround, as shown in my reply ... not ideal, but it keeps the work done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I managed to do something similar to what i need with

```
[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetForegroundWindow")]
[return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow([InAttribute()] IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetForegroundWindow")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "BringWindowToTop")]
[return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool BringWindowToTop([InAttribute()] IntPtr hWnd);

IntPtr old = GetForegroundWindow();
LeftClick(hw, x, y);
SetForegroundWindow(old);
BringWindowToTop(old);
```

The downside is, the "clicked" form still pops up for a graction of second, giving a bad style effect. Any other hint that helps keeping the form in the background is wellcome :)